# Paineis em Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gostaria de fazer uma pagina em Angular que ficasse parecido com a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que nada mais é que uma pagina com vários painéis, que adicionarei uma lista de informação dentro deles... Qual componente posso usar para conseguir esse resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há necessidade de componentes externos. Utilize uma combinação de [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) e CSS:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.paineis = ['Painel1','Painel2','Painel3','Painel4','Painel5','Painel6']; 
});
```

```css
.painel
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:10px 5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div class='painel' ng-repeat='i in paineis'>{{i}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```